# Java SWT: How to use multiple layouts per Composite?

Tags: java, swt

I have a class which extends Composite and what I want is to have a title (label in this case) followed by three controls on a separate row as follows:

Title

[Button] TEXT [BUTTON]

So far I have the code which adds in the Button, text, button but I don't know how to add in the label at the top of these three.

How can I add in the title (label) at the top, followed by the three controls at the bottom?

```
public class PageControl extends Composite {

    private Button nextPage;
    private Button previousPage;
    private Text text;
    private Label label;

    public PageControl(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
        gridLayout.numColumns = 3;
        gridLayout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = false;

        previousPage = new Button(this, style);
        previousPage.setText("Previous");
        previousPage.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_CENTER));

        text = new Text(this, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
        GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_CENTER);

        GC gc = new GC(text);
        gridData.minimumWidth = gc.textExtent("123456890", 0).x;
        text.setTextLimit(10);
        text.setLayoutData(gridData);

        nextPage = new Button(this, style);
        nextPage.setText("Next");
        nextPage.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_CENTER));

        Display display = Display.getCurrent();
        Color white = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE);
        this.setBackground(white);
        setLayout(gridLayout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the label span the three columns:

```
Label label = new Label(this, SWT.LEFT);
label.setText("title");

label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 3, 1));
```